# Aerospike Management Console: No batch query throughput

Tags: aerospike

How to see batch query throughput in AMC (Aerospike Management Console) ? I am using community edition. I am able to see read request made without batch but not made through batch. Or any other tool that can be used for same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The AMC dashboard includes the ability to filter for and visualize [statistics](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/amc/user_guide/community/statistics_nodes.html). This includes a list of [batch-index](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/guide/batch.html#batch-index) related [metrics](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/reference/metrics/#batch_errors). The cumulative metric [`batch_index_initiate`](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/reference/metrics/#batch_index_initiate) and the realtime metric [`batch_index_queue`](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/reference/metrics/#batch_index_queue) are probably interesting to you.

However, the number of records read per-second through batch-index is not something you can see from AMC. In the batch index protocol, the records in those batch requests get split and placed on the single record transaction queues and threads. What you can do is initiate the `batch_index_reads` micro-benchmark using [`asinfo`](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/tools/asinfo/) then analyze it with [`asloglatency`](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/tools/asloglatency/#micro-benchmarks).

Comment: The batch-index protocol was added in [release 3.6.0](http://www.aerospike.com/download/server/notes.html#3.6.0) of the server. Most of the clients now use batch-index as their default batch protocol, but still let you switch to the legacy batch-direct.